# Lyx - Editing the document class

Tags: beamer, lyx, document-classes, class-options

I am using LyX Beamer but want to the option `[t]`. Using Document -> Settings -> Document Class if I choose presentation (beamer) and put the `[t]` in custom it does not compile. Is there a way to define the class in the preamble so I can modify this option?

Comment: Do you put `t` or `[t]` in the settings dialog? It should be the former, LyX adds the brackets.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Well I wasted an hour, thanks much. Cheers